# Object inheritance

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance

```
function Foo() {
    this.SayFoo = function() {
        console.log('Foo');
    };
}

function Bar() {
    this.SayBar = function() {
        console.log('Bar');
    };
}

Foo.prototype = new Bar();

var fooBar = new Foo();
fooBar.SayBar();
```

This obviously works, but is it the correct way to do it?

Is there any way to make use of jQuery's `$.extend` or something similar in order to achieve the same inheritance results?

Including other frameworks besides jQuery is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually multiple ways to do inheritance in JavaScript: neoclassical, prototypal, and functional.  Douglas Crockford has nothing but bad things to say about neoclassical inheritance—the method you have above, and the method most Java/C# developers think will be the most natural.  The reason revolves around all the awkward things you have to do to get it right—setting the prototype, setting the constructor, etc.  Also, setting the prototype to a `new` instance of the parent class, like you have above, is usually frowned upon strongly, I believe because it complicates handling parameters with the base ctor.

If you're really sold on the neoclassical method, here's a [great link](http://www.amirharel.com/2010/03/22/javascript-inheritance/) that really goes over it.

The key part I reproduce for you here:

```
function Inherit(sub,super){
    var thinF = function(){};
    thinF.prototype = super.prototype;
    sub.prototype = new thinF();
    sub.prototype.constructor = sub;
    sub.super = super.prototype;
    if( super.prototype.constructor == Object.prototype.constructor ){
        super.prototype.constructor = super;
    }
}
```

FWIW Here's an example of functional inheritance that also highlights something you **don't** get with the neoclassical method: encapsulation/information hiding.

```
function eventRaiser(protectedStuff) {
    protectedStuff = protectedStuff || {}; 
    var that = {};
    var events = {};  //private

    protectedStuff.raise = function(key) {
        if (!events[key]) return;
            for (var i = 0; i < events[key].funcs.length; i++)
                events[key].funcs[i].apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    };

    that.subscribe = function(key, func) {
        if (!events[key])
            events[key] = { name: key, funcs: [] };
        events[key].funcs.push(func);
    };

    return that;
}        

function widget() {
    var protectedStuff = {};
    var that = eventRaiser(protectedStuff);

    that.doSomething = function() { 
        alert("doing something"); 
        protectedStuff.raise("doStuffEvent");
    };

    return that;
}

$(function() {
    var w = widget();
    w.subscribe("doStuffEvent", function(){ alert("I've been raised"); });
    w.doSomething();

    w.protectedStuff.raise("doStuffEvent"); //error!!!!!  raise is protected
    w.raise("doStuffEvent"); //and this obviously won't work
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, setting `prototype` to an instance is the correct way to do it.

Comment: You've got it reversed. Instances of `Foo` will have the `SayBar` method in its prototype chain, but instances of `Bar` do not have `SayFoo`.

Comment: Im not sure if im following you. The fooBar instance gets boths the methods (SayFoo and SayBaar), so why would it matter which one it uses?